# How to remove white spaces in the graph plot in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a problem after plotting the graph with matplolib using the python. I got the figure but the figure is having the white spaces of which i don't require. I have read most of the links that were provided by stack overflow but none is regarding to my issue. Now, I want to remove white spaces and require the whole image with picture.

Actually, I am new to the plot in python. I have created a plot of which the black colour is  box and the grey colour is the frame.
I created the top vie of the 3D plot [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAWQI.png)  as an image(.png) using the following code.

```
def cuboid(center, size): 
   
    ox, oy, oz = center
    l, w, h = size

   ###Added the fig in order to be able to plot it later
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') ##plot the project cuboid
    
    X=[ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2] ##corner points of the cuboid
    Y=[oy+w/2,oy-w/2,oy-w/2,oy+w/2,oy+w/2,oy-w/2,oy-w/2,oy+w/2]
    Z=[oz-h/2,oz-h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz-h/2,oz-h/2]
#    ax.scatter(X,Y,Z,c='g',marker='o')  #the plot before rotated

    X_new = ([]) #attaining new corner points after rotated
    Y_new = ([])
    Z_new = ([])

    for i in range(0,8):
 
        c=np.matrix([[X[i]], ##reading every corner points into matrix format
                    [Y[i]],
                    [Z[i]]])
        u=Rot_Mat*c ##rotating every corner point with the rotation matrix
        
        X_new = np.append(X_new, u.item(0)) ##appending the corner points with the neighbours
        Y_new = np.append(Y_new, u.item(1))
        Z_new = np.append(Z_new, u.item(2))
        
        print('\nvertex=\n',c)
        print('\nnew_vertex=\n',u)
        
        ###Doing a dot product between Rot_Mat and c as earlier but using np.dot as it is necessary with Numpy format, reshaping from(3,1) to (3)
        side[i,:] = np.dot(Rot_Mat, c).reshape(3)

    sides = [[side[0],side[1],side[2],side[3]], ##defining the 6 sides of cuboid
            [side[4],side[5],side[6],side[7]], 
            [side[0],side[1],side[4],side[5]], 
            [side[2],side[3],side[4],side[5]], 
            [side[1],side[2],side[5],side[6]],
            [side[4],side[7],side[0],side[3]]]
    
    ax.scatter(X_new,Y_new,Z_new,c='blue',marker='')  #the plot of corner points after rotated
    
 

    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(sides, facecolors='black', linewidths=1, edgecolors='black', alpha=.25)) ###This draw the plane sides as requred 
    fig.tight_layout()

   # Hide grid lines 
    ax.grid(False)

    # Hide axes ticks
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_zticks([])

    plt.axis('off') #removes the axes from grams
```

The initialisation data to create this cuboid plot is given as follows:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,6)) ##to obtain figure and dimensions of graph

ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], projection='3d')

#plot planes
p = Rectangle((0,-0.7), 4.5,1.4, color="lightgrey", alpha=0.2) #plots the background frame
ax.add_patch(p)

art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0, zdir="z")

i=pd.read_excel('Bond0.dump.xlsx')  ##to read the excel file format
X=i['x'] ## to import the variable on to axes from data set
Y=i['y']
Z=i['z']

j=pd.read_excel('paketone4000.dump.xlsx')  ##to read the excel file format
X=j['x'] ## to import the variable on to axes from data set
Y=j['y']
Z=j['z']

a=j['x']##import centre of mass from excel file format
b=j['y']
c=j['z']

#cuboid initialising parameters
center = [a[0], b[0], c[0]] ##centre of the body
length = 0.3 ##defining length, breadth, height
width = 0.4
height = 0.1
side = np.zeros((8,3))  ###This numpy vector will be used to store the position of the sides
```

The expected outcome is that i have to remove the white spaces in the picture and form a picture with the grey frame (vertical dimensions=(0,4.5), horizontal dimention=(-0.7,0.7))

Comment: Can anyone suggest an answer for this question as early as possible?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the work to edit my file. I need an answer or suggestion to this question. Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Is anyone there to answer or give suggestion for this question. I am waiting for the replies or comments.